# Should an interface provide a definition for an antagonist method?

Tags: c#, interface

Sorry if the question isn't clear; I couldn't find the best way to phrase it.
Which is the better practice?

Example:

```
public interface IActivable {
   void Activate();
   void Deactivate();
}
```

OR:

```
    public interface IActivable {
       void Activate();

    }

   public interface IDeactivable {

       void Deactivate();
   }
```

Comment: do the two methods logically go together? Can you have one implemented without the other?  This is an imlpementation decision, not a best practice question.

Comment: Sounds like you could also use IDisposable... activate in the constructor and deactivate in the Dispose method. That way you can make use of the using statement

Comment: @TheLethalCoder this depends extremely on what he is trying to do, and as far is i read about the using of IDisposable it is not always useful

Comment: @WiiMaxx That's why I posted it as a comment not answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Will all implementations of `IActivable` be required to implemented `Deactivate`?
- Will all clients of `IActivable` need both `Activate` and `Deactivate`?

If you've answered "no" to any of those two questions, it might be a good idea to break it into two separate interfaces, according to the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/interface-segregation-principle.html).

Answer (score 2):

In your case you may want to know if object (that implements `IActivable`) *is active* or not. So it could be better to *redesign* the interface into

```
  public interface IActivable {
    Boolean IsActive {get; set;}
  }
```

in case you want to have, say, *explicit* `Activate()` method for the redisigned interface you can do it via *extension methods*:

```
  public static class ActivableExtensions {
    public static void Activate(this IActivable source) {
      if (null == source)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");   

      source.IsActive = true;
    }
  }
```

possible interface implementation:

```
  public MyClass: IActivable {
    private Boolean m_IsActive;

    private void CoreActivate() {...};
    private void CoreDeActivate() {...};

    public Boolean IsActive {
      get {
        return m_IsActive; 
      }
      set {
        if (value != m_IsActive) {
          if (value) 
            CoreActivate();
          else 
            CoreDeActivate();

          m_IsActive = value;
        } 
      }
    }
  }
```

...

```
  MyClass sample = new MyClass();

  // or (if you implement the extension method) you can put it
  // sample.Activate();
  sample.IsActive = true; // activate
  ...
  sample.IsActive = false; // deactivate
```

Comment: Great answer. Was hard to choose between yours and dcastro's.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your system. If there will be objects that can only be activated (or deactivated), then create two interfaces. If the two actions are tightly coupled and always go together, then one interface will suffice. As **Jonesopolis** mentioned in his comment, it is an implementation decision.

Answer (score 0):

If your objects implementing IActivable can be Activated and deactivated the first interface is what you need.
Id you have different objects and an object can only be Activated and never deactivated or you have some object that are only activated, some that are only deactivated and some that are both activated and deactivated the two interfaces are what you need.

maybe if you explain better what you want to achieve we can help better.